# Does ubuntu support dell inspiron one 2310 with nvidia geforce 520mx?

Tags: drivers, video, dell

I have found that ubuntu support dell inspiron one 2310 with AMD video card,but I'm not sure it support nvidia geforce 520mx or not?

ps:I have tried my best to install the driver for 520mx on fedora,but never success.

Comment: Neither the Inspiron nor the grforce are on the list of fully supported hardware here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification Still, that doesn't mean it won't work. Try it and enable the restricted driver after installing.

Comment: There is A LOTTT of hardware not mention in the certification page of Ubuntu that is actually supported. Supported 100%. The reason of this because there are way too many models of too many companies. I have, up to now, been with at least 30 models that are not mentioned there and work 100%. Just saying it for some additional information

Answer (score 1):

For what I know DELL is one the companies that has good support with Ubuntu. The deal with the Nvidia card might be a little tricky but I highly recommend using the PPA for the Nvidia/Ati cards. It has solved a problem with another Nvidia mobile model I had and another 2. It has support for your card also.

To install the latest drivers from the PPA do the following:

In the terminal type: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Then update your repositories by typing in the terminal this: `sudo apt-get update`.

Afterwards go to the **Additional Drivers** app by typing in the dash **Drivers**. Install the Nvidia recommended driver from the list and reboot.

This solved several cases of Old Nvidia cards and some mobile Nvidia cards.